# How many Faceless Men are there?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Considering that a Faceless Man is "no-one" and can change appearances at will, is there any mention of how large their order actually is?

For all we know it could just be two people: The Kindly Man and Waif....

Comment: In the show we've only seen at most 3 at a time, but AFAIK in the books there are quite a few in the headquarters

Comment: An order has no number.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### In the books, at least twelve

In *A Song of Ice and Fire*, Arya attends a meeting of eleven Faceless Men:

> **Eleven servants of the Many-Faced God gathered that night beneath the
> temple, more than she had ever seen together at one time**. Only the
> lordling and the fat fellow arrived by the front door; the rest came
> by secret ways, through tunnels and hidden passages. They wore their
> robes of black and white, but as they took their seats each man pulled
> his cowl down to show the face he had chosen to wear that day. Their
> tall chairs were carved of ebony and weirwood, like the doors of the
> temple above. The ebon chairs had weirwood faces on their backs, the
> weirwood chairs faces of carved ebony.
>
> —*A Dance with Dragons*

This group has some overlap with those Arya has seen before:

> After three hours of wine and words, the priests took their leave …
> all but **the kindly man, the waif, and the one whose face bore the
> marks of plague.**
>
> —*A Dance with Dragons*

The text seems to indicate that Arya is not counting herself in this number, so that makes a dozen Faceless Men. **We at least know that there are significantly more than two Faceless Men.**

Other possible or definite Faceless Men have appeared in the books. Samwell Tarly, for instance, met "Pate" after the real Pate had died, and thus "Pate" was probably a Faceless Man.

> “My thanks.” There was something about the pale, soft youth that he
> misliked, but he did not want to seem discourteous, so he added, “My
> name’s not Slayer, truly. I’m Sam. Samwell Tarly.”
>
> “I’m Pate,” the other said, “like the pig boy.”
>
> —*A Feast for Crows*

However, given that eleven is the maximum number of Faceless Men ever mentioned to be *in one place* at the same time, we cannot assume that there are more based on other individuals seen in the books, given the well-known propensity of the Faceless Men for disguise.

It's also worth noting that the previous passage suggests that the Faceless Men are not much more numerous, since eleven is the most Arya has ever seen together.

### In the TV series, at least three

In the TV series *Game of Thrones*, we know of three Faceless Men:

- Arya Stark
- The Waif
- "Jaqen H'ghar"

**Given that the Waif and Jaqen appear at the same time, we know they are different people. We can also assume that neither of them is Arya Stark, making three.**

Comment: So you don't buy into the "Fight Club" fan theory running around now?

Comment: @Skooba - That the Waif is a manifestation of Arya's subconscious? Not particularly. Is she beating herself up, then?

Comment: Yup, that is the one. It has to be one of the more shoddy theories I had read. Especially now, I don't think she stabbed herself. I think a lot of these theorists have not read the book either.

Comment: In the TV Show, do you not count the body movers as faceless men? Or are they the Janitors of the organisation?

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder - I'm not totally sure, so I didn't include them.

Comment: I think I reacall a scene from the show where "Jaqen" once drinks that deadly potion, dies, Arya goes crazy and starts ripping off faces from the body. The last is actually hers(!). Then Jaqen steps up behind her and calms her down. I think there was even the dialog "who is that", "no one". So once upon a time there were at least 4 Faceless men, including Arya.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, there were 11 at the gathering, which I don't believe included the waif, so that's a dozen. However, I think it would be safe and wise to assume that surely there were other faceless men of unknown numbers throughout the world on current 'missions', no? It seemed that the ones at the meeting were sort of heads of the operation, not the entire organization. It seems to me that no number will ever be substantiated as the mystery only serves to add to the mystique of the order. Large numbers of excellently-trained assassins who don't fail? A force to be reckoned with surely. A small number of said assassins? A very exclusive guild, indeed, and one whose services will not be cheap.
(Also, regarding a previous answer, Arya Stark would NOT make three since she was not technically yet a faceless man. She was sort of on probationary terms, I think.)